# Numerical Integration Function issue

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

I am trying to plot a function which takes as arguments two other functions and performs an integration.  I originally defined it analytically as so:

```
T3[tao_, Tf_] = 
 Exp[ -Integrate[1/tao[t] , t] ] (Integrate[
    1/tao[t] Exp[Integrate[1/tao[t], t]] Tf[t], t, 
    GeneratedParameters -> C] )
```

And this works well for simple functions, I can solve for the constant of integration like so:

```
taoFunction[t_] = t;
functionToPlot[t_] = 5*HeavisideTheta[t - 3]
Solve[T3[taoFunction[#] &, functionToPlot[#] &] == 0, C[1]] /. t -> 0
```

And then plot the function:

```
Plot[Evaluate[ 
  T3[ taoFunction[#] &, functionToPlot[#] &] /. C[1] -> 0], {t, 0, 
  10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}]
```

However when I try with more complicated functions, it chokes on the integration:

```
complicatedTaoFunction[t_]  = Sin[t] + 3;
testFunction[t_] = 100 t^0.5*E^-(t/0.5);
Solve[T3[complicatedTaoFunction[#] &, testFunction[#]  &] == 0,  C[1], Reals]
```

Thus I tried to define the same function using numerical integration, so that the upper limits of the NIntegrate[] will be the independent variable like so,

```
u[z_?NumericQ, tao_] :=  NIntegrate[1/tao[x], {x, 0.01, z}]
T3[Tf_] = 
 Exp[-u[t, taoFunction[#] & ]] (Integrate[1/t  Exp[u[t, taoFunction[#] & ]] Tf[t], t, 
    GeneratedParameters -> C] )
```

The NIntegrate function works:

```
Plot[u[y, taoFunction[#] &], {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-2, 5}}]
```

However, when I try to plot the function that integrates this function, I get an invalid integration limits error as well as non-numerical integrand errors,

```
Plot[ Evaluate[ T3[functionToPlot[#] &] /. C[1] -> 0 ], {t, 1, 10}]
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your function u[z_?NumericQ, tao_] contains no other pure functions.  T3 definition on the other hand already contains both u[, #&] and new Tf, to which your refer in Plot. Confusion arises. Try to replace u[t,#&] by something like u[t,Function[xx,xx]] to avoid the confusion. In general your approach is overcomplicated and difficult to follow.

Comment: @Acus Yes, the pure functions were, ironically, an effort to simplify the complexity.  The intent was always to replace them with a function.  I have edited the post and substituted a simple function in their place, which also makes the function identical to the analytical function and attempted to make it easier to follow.

Comment: u[t, taoFunction[#] & ] in your T3[Tf_] will not compute since u[z_?NumericQ, tao_] is defined for numeric first argument, whereas in T3 your ask for symbolic argument.